# urllib2 HTTPError: HTTP Error 414: Request-URI Too Large

Tags: python, http, urllib2

I have a URL that is 1029 character. I paste it into Firefox, and it loads fine. However, in Python's urllib2, I get HTTPError: HTTP Error 414: Request-URI Too Large.

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(csv_url)
```

Any reason why it works in Firefox but not in urllib2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it's how the rest of the request is formatted by Firefox, vs. urllib2 -- with the resulting urllib2 packet coming in larger.  Can you inspect the packet size using Firebug (a web console for Firefox -- https://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: I would even go a step further and have a look with something like wireshark. Firefox might do some URL cutting which might happen beyond the sight of Firebug.

Comment: Have you witnessed this behaviour w/ Firefox? I've used it pretty extensively, and I can tell you it makes doing web development a snap. It pretty flawlessly represents the data exchange & formats it beautifully. I'm not criticizing Wireshark (which I also love) -- but LAN analyzers are better at troubleshooting layer 1 - 3 issues (just my two cents).

Comment: Not exactly this behaviour, but I witnessed some magic regarding the source code. AFAIR this was Firebug related. Since then I stopped to trust the authenticity of Firebug's output.